# devdocs.io doesn't seem to work offline

Tags: firefox, browser, documentation, offline-files

OS: Linux Mint 18.3
Browser: FireFox 70.0.1

Ironically the documentation for devdocs.io is somewhat scarce. It seems there is no add-on for FireFox for devdocs, although there is one for Chrome.

I'm currently not even sure whether the actual documents for the various software you "install" are indeed installed locally, or just something that enables you to *search* offline.

My test is a simple one:

1. while online I check the checkboxes for the things that interest me
2. I go to: https://devdocs.io/offline
3. I check "Install updates automatically"
4. I click "Install all" if I haven't already
5. On the "Preferences" page I check "Automatically download documentation for offline use"
6. then I close the browser
7. I switch off my Wifi connection in the computer and re-open the browser.
8. I point my browser to https://devdocs.io/offline... "this site can't be reached"

What should I be doing that I'm not? Or have I got this all wrong????

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in Chrome on my machine.

The project's GitHub thread is here: https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/devdocs/issues/1124 (my issue).

The person who answered me told me there that she "couldn't help me" and that a "Support worker" is meant to run when you go //devdocs.io when offline, so you don't just get a message about not being able to reach the site.

I have a number of add-ons in Firefox. One of these could conceivably be guilty for hampering this.  The idea would be to disable them all, and then add them back one-by-one.  I may get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `privacy.firstparty.isolate` in `about:config` Firefox page. That worked for me